# Touchpad not working on HP Pavilion X2 12

Tags: touchpad, 16.04, hp

I recently bought an HP Pavilion X2 12 (http://store.hp.com/UKStore/Merch/Product.aspx?id=T1E48EA&opt=ABU&sel=NTB)

I installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 and all hardware worked perfectly out of the box, but not my touchpad. Even touchscreen worked, but not the touchpad.

Xinput doesn't list the device. And in the boot log I find this :

```
[ 2.440927] hid-rmi 0003:06CB:7D29.0001: rmi_scan_pdt: Done with PDT scan.
[ 2.453918] hid-rmi 0003:06CB:7D29.0001: No 2D sensor found, giving up.
[ 2.453919] hid-rmi 0003:06CB:7D29.0001: Error while initializing F11 (-19).
[ 2.456476] hid-rmi 0003:06CB:7D29.0001: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [SYNAPTICS Synaptics HIDUSB TouchPad V03] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2.1/input0
[ 2.456478] hid-rmi 0003:06CB:7D29.0001: Device failed to be properly configured
```

I tried upgrading the kernel to 4.5 and 4.6RC6, but none of these helped. The hid-rmi driver seems to be the problem. Can that driver be replaced, updated or exchanged somehow?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, I have the exact same issue, so I opened the following bug to see if we can get this fixed properly: [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1611081](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1611081)

Comment: Great! I have tried later kernels up to 4.7 but that hasn't helped either. I checked that the bug affects me too. Hopefully it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out! Here is what I did:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modules
```

Add `hid_generic` at the bottom of that file.
Save and close.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add `blacklist hid_rmi` at the bottom of that file.
Save and close.

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo echo 3 06cb 7d29 1 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_generic/drivers/hid\:hid-generic/new_id
```

The numbers in the above command correspond to the `dmesg` output for my device. This will load and use the less advanced `hid-generic` instead of `hid_rmi`. It won't handle gestures and such, but for me that is ok. All I need is move, click and scroll.

Hopefully a future update will fix `hid_rmi` for this device too, allowing more advanced functions.

To make the change permanent I did this:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Add the line

```
echo 3 06cb 7d29 1 | tee /sys/module/hid_generic/drivers/hid\:hid-generic/new_id
```

above `exit 0`. Save and exit, and run

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
```

Now it works after every boot.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. But it happened after I did a recent update for my 14.04. Did some search on the internet and found out 16.04 has problems with Synaptics. This fix is what I found in the end, may be you can try.

Go to TERMINAL and type this command:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo reboot
```

This fix is taken from [this thread on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322413)

Comment: Did this work for the x2 12, or was it a different device?